# Block recipent email in postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I have a postfix MX server setup with virtual users in sql tables. One of the old users I had is getting a large amount of spam, and the catchall address is getting it all. Is there a way to prevent all mail to a specific recipient to be blocked and not delivered to the catch all?

Thanks,
Nat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a table called `/etc/postfix/sender_access` that looks like

```
annoying_person@irritating.domain.com  REJECT
```

and this in your `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  ...
  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
  ...
```

then the SMTP daemon will refuse the message with

```
554 5.7.1 <annoying_person@irritating.domain.com>: Sender address rejected: Access denied
```

Comment: im trying to block mail TO an email not who mail is FROM

Comment: got it, it was what you said but instead of "check_sender_access" it needs to be "check_recipient_access"

Comment: D'oh, yes of course, sorry about that, I cut and pasted from my own config without passing it through my brain.  Glad you got it sorted anyway.